# How to split a long input into multiple items in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and have been trying to code a program where I enter many things at once and it splits them into different strings, ints, etc. depending on what they are but I can't figure out how.

I want to be able to input, for example, "What is 7 plus 9?" and code it so it assigns the first number (7) to int a, the second number (9) to int b, recognize the word "plus" to be the operator. This would then go to a simple calculator program which I have already coded fine and would then output the answer.

How do I code it so it can split the entire input into multiple individual items? I was thinking there must be some function for a format of input in which case I could define input as string1, string2, int a, string 3, int b, and just have it know the start/end of each by the spaces. Anything you have in mind that could do this please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: So you want a human-language parser and you thought you'd just casually plod along on to Stack Overflow and ask for the code? You know that software like Google and Siri takes billions of dollars to research and develop, right?

Comment: That was just an example, sorry if I offended you but I just figured that would be an easy way to explain the types of things I wanted to do.

Comment: You didn't "offend" me; you simply asked a question that's _way_ too broad for this website. Or any website.

Comment: I think what Lightness is saying is that this is not exactly a project for someone who is "new to C++". You might want to start with evaluating mathematical expressions such as "7 + 9" rather than questions in human language. Even then, such a project is far from trivial.

Comment: I have already made the mathematical expression part, I was trying to make it so it would just be able to take it all as one input. Explaining how to split up the input "7 + 9" would answer my question just as well.

Comment: if you made your grammer simpler by not using English words and only supporting ()+-?* you could get away with easily hand coding it, however antlr would make this extremely simple and you could probably find an example easily. what makes what you want to do difficult is the fact you want to support natural language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ideally a lexer and parser like antlr or lex/yacc would be great but the learning curve is steep

Comment: I have googled around a little bit and that looks like it would work. I'll see if I can find some examples or tutorials since it looks way above my level and hopefully I can get that to work. Thanks!